# El mismo registro se repite en diferentes páginas de paginación en API REST Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, djangorestframework, nginx

Obtengo el mismo registro con la misma ID de repetición exacta en la página 16 y página 22 de mis resultados devueltos por la API y al revisar la base de datos solo existen un único registro con ese ID:

Pagina 16

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Página 22

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría solucionarlo?. Estoy usando Postgres como base de datos y NGINX como servidor Web proxy.

A nivel de código el servicio está programado de la siguiente manera:

```
class SellDistStoProductView(ModelViewSet):
     permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,IsSavedRole,IsNotLaboratory)
     queryset = None
     parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
     serializer_class = SellDistStoProductSerializer
     filter_backends = [
        DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter
     ]
     filterset_fields = ["product", "product__provider_id", "provider", 
       "provider__state_prin_venue", "product__sectors", "product__categories", 
       "provider__type_provider"
     ]
     search_fields = ["product__code_product", "product__name_product", 
       "product__description", "product__brand_id__name_brand", 
       "product__active_substances__active_substance", "provider__business_name", 
       "product__categories__name_category", "product__active_substance_custom", 
       "product__sectors_custom", "product__sectors__name_sector"]
     ordering_fields = ['order_by_sector', 'order_by_category']
     pagination_class = Pagination

     def get_queryset(self):
         provider = Provider.objects.get(administrator=self.request.user)
    
         if self.request.GET.get('unlab') != None:
             queryset = SellProduct.objects.select_related("product", "provider", 
               "coupon_percentage", "coupon_quality").filter(Q(provider=provider), 
               Q(product__provider_id=None)).only("id_sell", "product", "provider", 
               "stock", "iva", "price", "coupon_percentage", "coupon_quality")
          else:
             queryset = SellProduct.objects.select_related("product", "provider", 
               "coupon_percentage", 
               "coupon_quality").filter(Q(provider=provider)).only("id_sell", 
               "product", "provider", "stock", "iva", "price", "coupon_percentage", 
               "coupon_quality")
    
          return queryset

     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

     def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
           serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
           return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Y la clase paginadora está definida así:

```
class Pagination(PageNumberPagination):
   page_size = 100
   page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución a este tipo de incidencia es asegurarse de implementar:

```
.distinct() or .order_by()
```

En las consultas paginadas, así se evita que la busqueda y los filtros afecten la página que se está consultando tomando productos que antes se habían consultado, esto es debido a que el ORM cambia de posiciones los productos cuando se consultan secuencialmente.